# Story about rescue mission on Mercury or Venus

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book about 12 years ago (it already looked old back then IIRC) about two people leaving the safety of the domes protecting the colonies on the planet (either Venus or Mercury) from the Sun, I believe for a rescue mission.
Their vehicle breaks down during their expedition, requiring one of them to carry the other back to the colony.
At some point they meet a silicon life form.

I read the story in German back then, if that is any help.

Comment: Was the whole book about the story of that rescue mission? Or was the rescue on Venus or Mercury one story or one chapter in a collection of space adventure stories? Was the book an Adult Book or a Young Adult (or Juvenile) Book?

Comment: @user14111 As far as I remember, the plot as described was the main part of the story, so not just a chapter, and I don't think there were multiple stories in that book. Since I was much younger than today, I would assume it is either a Juvenile or Young adult book.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, given the vague description, but it might be [Lucky Starr and the Big Sun of Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Starr_and_the_Big_Sun_of_Mercury).

Comment: @HarryJohnston I apologize for being so vague, it's just been a long time since reading that story … anyway, I think for the longest part of the book, there is no named character (or any human, really) besides the two main characters.

Answer (score 3):

The John Varley story "[In the Bowl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50783)" fits many of the points mentioned by the questioner.

Fits:

- "Two people leave domes" - check
- "on Venus" - check
- "old in 2005" - published in 1975
- "silicon life form" - the jewels they are searching for turn
  out to be alive
- "read it in German" - [check](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1523908)

Sorta:

- "Their vehicle breaks down requiring one of them to carry the other back" - in the story, one of the protagonists
  gets blinded and has to be walked back led by the other. They don't have a vehicle, just robotic porter kinda things
- (from comment) "I think for the longest part of the book, there is no
  named character (or any human, really) besides the two main
  characters" - check, except it's a story, not a book

Miss:

- "I believe for a rescue mission" - they are out prospecting